# I found this diagram - How do I make it in LaTeX?

Tags: diagrams

I found the following diagram in a book allegedly written entirely in LaTeX. As a TeX amateur I was wondering if any of you knew how I could make this.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1mm}*{4}{|p{5mm}}|}
\hline
& A & B & A & B \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1mm}*{4}{|@{\,}p{6mm}}|}
\hline
& A & B & A & B \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I thought it would be much harder than this to make such a diagram!

Comment: @JackieCarson You're welcome. And sorry to disappoint you. ;-)

Comment: You might use `boldline` to easily obtain thick inner vertical rules, as the image in the question.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks! Will do if the OP confirms if that is a requirement (rather than an issue with the viewer, what I took it to be).

Comment: Oh! yes. I didn't think  of this possibility.

Comment: @Bernard I didn't think of it as a requirement at all. I wasn't attempting to 100% perfectly recreate what the chart has. I was just unsure on how one would go about doing this. Thanks again for the help